# Do not register the component if there are no dependent beans using spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I create `spring-boot-starter`, which registers some bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ClusterJProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "clusterj", name = {"connectString", "dataBaseName"})
public class ClusterJAutoConfiguration {

    private final ClusterJProperties clusterJConfigProperties;

    @Autowired
    public ClusterJAutoConfiguration(ClusterJProperties clusterJConfigProperties) {
        this.clusterJConfigProperties = clusterJConfigProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        Properties clusterJProperties = new Properties();
        clusterJProperties.setProperty("com.mysql.clusterj.connectstring", clusterJConfigProperties.getConnectString());
        clusterJProperties.setProperty("com.mysql.clusterj.database", clusterJConfigProperties.getDataBaseName());
        clusterJProperties.putAll(clusterJConfigProperties.getProperties());
        return ClusterJHelper.getSessionFactory(clusterJProperties);
    }
}
```

I want using this starter in another module. For this, I created a component, and inject this bean there:

```
@Component
public class GetEntityHandler implements VoidTreeNodeHandler {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public GetEntityHandler(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override

    public void handle(TreeContext context, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
       //do smth
    }
}
```

But, when, properties `clusterj.connectString` and `clusterj.connectString` not present in `application.yml`, bean `SessionFactory` not create. It is ok, but `GetEntityHandler` want to create, and fall with error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'getEntityHandler' defined in file [GetEntityHandler.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mysql.clusterj.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

How to make my `GetEnityNandler` component not be created if the `SessionFactory` bean is not present in context?

Comment: Maybe I'm unclear about your ask, but your ClusterJAutoConfiguration is only ran if there is certain properties available, therefore, you know if they are there, there will also be a SessionFactory. Can you just add @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "clusterj", name = {"connectString", "dataBaseName"}) to your GetEntityHandler?

Comment: Yes I can. And it works. But how correct is it? If I want to change the names of properties, I have to remember that they are written in two places. I thought there is a better way.

Comment: You could try @ConditionalOnBean(SessionFactory.class) that way it's dependent on your SessionFactory been being initialized.